Why does the right shift operator give unexpected results for negative numbers?
I'm trying to understand how the right shift (>>) operator works in JavaScript, especially when dealing with negative numbers. I know that the left shift operator (<<) effectively multiplies the number by powers of 2. For example:

12 << 1 gives 24 (equivalent to 12 * 2).
12 << 3 gives 96 (equivalent to 12 * 2 * 2 * 2).
Similarly, -12 << 3 gives -96.

but when it comes to the right shift operator, I'm encountering some unexpected results. I know that right shifting divides the number by 2:
12 >> 1 gives 6, which makes sense.
But when I try it with a negative number:
-27 >> 1 gives -14, but I was expecting -13.
Is there something I'm missing about how right shifts work with negative numbers?

Is left and right shifting negative integers defined behavior? and Right shifting negative numbers in C

If you're about JavaScript why have you tagged c and c++ but not JavaScript?

Since it's called "bitshift", look at the binary representations of the numbers before and after the shift.

Also provide a [mcve] so that it is clear if you're asking about c++ or javascript.

The result of right-shifting a negative value is implementation-defined.

JavaScript is an implementation of ECMAScript, in which >> is specified to perform a sign-filling right shift on the two’s complement representation, via clauses 7.1.6, 13.9.2, 13.15.4, 13.15.3, and 6.1.6.1.10 of EMCAScript 2022 Language Specification. It also has >>> for unsigned right shift, via clauses 7.1.6, 13.9.3, 13.15.4, 13.15.3, and 6.1.6.1.11.

Because you are using the signed 2's complement to represent the negative number
27 in signed 2's complement is 0000000000011011, assuming you are using 16 bits, and if you apply 27>>1 you'll get 0000000000001101 which is 13
-27 in signed 2's complement is 1111111111100101, and if you apply -27>>1 you'll get 1111111111110010 which is -14 (the leftmost bit will always be a 1 since it's a negative number)
